# jQuery .promise syntax error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jquery .promise for the first time and I am doing something totally wrong.  i get a syntax error.  Please help.  I have a SharePoint site and I am using REST API to query a list.  My goal is to get a count of ticket types and to create a jqplot chart.  I get a syntax error when i try to use jquery .promise but it looks fine.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
var ticketArray = new Array();
var myData = new Array();

var i = 0;
$.getJSON("../practice/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/TicketType", function(data) {

    //iterate through all returned Ticket list items and store in an object
    $.each(data.d.results, function(i, result) {
        //get item property
        var TicketObj = {};
        TicketObj.TicketType = result.Title;
        TicketObj.Count = 0;

        ticketArray[i] = TicketObj;
        i++;
    });


    promise = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        //dataType: "json",
        url: "../practice/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/TicketingSystems?$select=TypeOfTicket",
        cache: false
    });
    promise.done(function(data) {
            //success : function(data) {
            //iterate through all returned Ticket list items and get count
            $.each(data.d.results, function(i, result) {
                for (var x = 0; x < ticketArray.length; x++) {
                    //console.log("Ticket Type: "+result.TypeOfTicket);
                    if (ticketArray[x].TicketType == result.TypeOfTicket) {
                        ticketArray[x].Count += 1;
                        console.log("Ticket Count: " + ticketArray[x].Count);
                    }
                }
            }); //each()
        )
    };
    promise.done(function(data) {
            $.each(ticketArray, function(index, value) {
                myData.push([ticketArray[index].TicketType, ticketArray[index].Count]);
            });
        )
    };
    //}
    var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot('chart1', [myData], {
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                showDataLabels: true
            }
        },
        legend: {
            show: true,
            location: 'e'
        }
    }); //end plot1
```

Comment: what is the syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

Use below script as is and let me know if this is fixed:)
Add reference to these three scripts:
1. /_layouts/15/SP.Runtime.js 
2./_layouts/15/SP.js 
3. //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js

```
                     <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    var ticketArray = new Array();
                    var myData = new Array();
                    getListData('TicketType').then(function (items) {
                        var ListEnumeratorTT = items.getEnumerator();
                        var i = 0;
                        while (ListEnumeratorTT.moveNext()) {
                            var currentItem = ListEnumeratorTT.get_current();
                            var TicketObj = {};
                            TicketObj.TicketType = currentItem.get_item('Title');
                            TicketObj.Count = 0;
                            ticketArray[i] = TicketObj;
                            i += 1;
                        }
                        getListData('TicketingSystems').then(function (items) {
                            var ListEnumeratorTS = items.getEnumerator();
                            var i = 0;
                            while (ListEnumeratorTS.moveNext()) {
                                var currentItem = ListEnumeratorTS.get_current();
                                for (var x = 0; x < ticketArray.length; x++) {
                                    if (ticketArray[x].TicketType == currentItem.get_item('TypeOfTicket')) {
                                        ticketArray[x].Count += 1;
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                            $.each(ticketArray, function (index, value) {
                                myData.push([ticketArray[index].TicketType, ticketArray[index].Count]);
                            });
                            var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot('chart1', [myData], {
                                seriesDefaults: {
                                    renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
                                    rendererOptions: {
                                        showDataLabels: true
                                    }
                                },
                                legend: { show: true, location: 'e' }
                            });//end plot1
                        });

                    });
                });
                function getListData(listTitle, success, error) {
                    var dfd = $.Deferred(function () {
                        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                        var web = context.get_web();
                        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
                        var items = list.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());

                        context.load(items);
                        context.executeQueryAsync(
                          function () {
                              dfd.resolve(items);

                          },
                          function (sender, args) {
                              dfd.reject(args);
                          }
                        );
                    });
                    return dfd.promise();
                }
            </script>
```

Comment: I really like your method.  I have copied the code to my site but I am having a hard time finding the following
1. /_layouts/15/SP.Runtime.js 
 2./_layouts/15/SP.js

Is there a reputable site I can download the files from

Comment: These are default sharepoint javascript library. If you are using SharePoint 2010 then path will be 1. /_layouts/SP.Runtime.js 2./_layouts/SP.js

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {


var ticketArray = new Array();  
var myData = new Array();

var i=0;
$.getJSON("../practice/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/TicketType",function(data) {

    //iterate through all returned Ticket list items and store in an object
    $.each(data.d.results, function(i,result) {
      //get item property
      var TicketObj = {};
      TicketObj.TicketType = result.Title;
      TicketObj.Count = 0;

      ticketArray[i] = TicketObj;   
      i++;
    });

promise = $.getJSON("../practice/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/TicketingSystems?$select=TypeOfTicket",function(data) {
    console.log("#1");
    //iterate through all returned Ticket list items and get count
    $.each(data.d.results, function(i,result) {
        for (var x=0; x<ticketArray.length; x++)
        {
            if (ticketArray[x].TicketType == result.TypeOfTicket)
            {
                ticketArray[x].Count +=1;
            }
        }
    });//each()     

});//getJSON    
promise.done(function(data) {
    console.log("#2");
    $.each(ticketArray, function (index, value) {           
        myData.push([ticketArray[index].TicketType, ticketArray[index].Count]); 

    });

    var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot('chart1',[myData], {
    seriesDefaults: {
       renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
       rendererOptions: {
        showDataLabels: true
       }
    },
    legend: { show:true, location: 'e' }
  });//end plot1
});
```

});